# Load zebra strip in ajax loaded table

Tags: ajax, load, strip

I tried to apply a zebra strip with an ajax loaded table but it's not work. I tried googling some suggestion over the net but no luck. Here's my code:

CSS:

```
<style>
.odd{background:#eeeeee}
</style>
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="../jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr:even").addClass("even");
    $("tr:odd").addClass("odd");
});

//supplier ajax viewer
 $(document).ready(function(stripTable) {
     $("#supplier_viewer").load("inc/stock_view.php");
$('tr:odd',this).addClass("odd");
     var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#supplier_viewer").load('inc/stock_view.php?randval='+ Math.random());
   }, 10000);
$('tr:odd',this).addClass("odd");
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
```

And this is where the table is loaded.

HTML:

```
<div id="supplier_view"></div>
```

I've tried to add

```
$('tr:even',this).addClass("even");
```

to the load stage but not work. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the classes to the element before they are actually loaded.

Try applying these classes when the loaded event is fired.

I would also recommend to use FireBug to view the generated html and see if the classes are really applied to the dynamically loaded data. (which I highly suspect not)

Once the data is loaded, you need to execute these two lines

```
$("tr:even").addClass("even");
$("tr:odd").addClass("odd");
```

But only after the data has been loaded to the div